# Type deduction and argument passing with variadic template templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, template-templates

I implemented a C++ equivalent of Python's chain function a while ago thanks to variadic templates. The function is used to iterate successively through many containers. Here is the old working version of the function using a generator named `ChainedObject`, whatever it is:

```
template<typename... Iterables>
auto chain(Iterables&&... iters)
    -> ChainObject<Iterables...>
{
    return /* ... */;
}
```

And the corresponding main:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::list<int>   li  = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
    for (auto& i: chain(vec, li))
    {
        // You can edit a range of iterables
        // as if there was only one of them.
        i *= 5;

        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That main worked fine. We don't care what there is in ChainObject for the problem, so let's see it. I tried to use template templates to ensure that the different collections used had the same `value_type` and modified the function `chain` the following way:

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class... Iterables>
auto chain(Iterables<T>&&... iters)
    -> ChainObject<T, Iterables...>
{
    return /* ... */;
}
```

I thought this would do the trick to ensure the `list` and `vector` from my previous main share a same type, but instead, I get the following error from GCC 4.7.1:

> In function 'int main()':
>
> error: no matching function for call to 'chain(std::vector&, std::list&)'
>
> note: candidates are:
>
> note: `ChainObject<T, Iterables ...> chain(Iterables<T>&& ...) [with T = int; Iterables = {std::vector, std::list}`]
>
> note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '`std::list<int>`' to '`std::list<int>&&`'
>
> note: `ChainObject<T, Iterables ...> chain(Iterables<T>&& ...) [with T = int; Iterables = {std::vector, std::list}]`
>
> note: no known conversion for argument 2 from '`std::list<int>`' to '`std::list<int>&&`'
>
> error: unable to deduce 'auto&' from ''

It seems that the problem comes from argument passing to the function taking rvalue references. However, I really don't understand why my first version worked fine, and note the one using template templates.

Comment: Have you tried passing an lvalue reference instead of an rvalue ?

Comment: Don't use template templates in combination with containers. It will fail as soon as allocators are used. Just check for equality of the nested `value_type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the `T&&` template magic only works for type parameters (it works by deducing `T` as eg. `int&` if needed - for lvalue arguments). It can't work for template template arguments, where the actual type is `X<T>&&` - `X` must be a class template in this case, not something like "reference-to-class-template". So in the end you have to pass a rvalue-reference, which you cannot implicitly get from a lvalue (variable).

That said, I would suggest you to revert to your earlier code and check that the `value_type`s are the same (or compatible, etc., whatever gets you going) with SFINAE.

Rough code sketch (for strict equality):

```
template <class ... Ts> struct all_types_equal
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <class T>
struct all_types_equal<T>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};
template <class T, class ... Rest>
struct all_types_equal<T, T, Rest...>
{
  static const bool value = all_types_equal<T, Rest...>::value;
};

template<typename... Iterables>
auto chain(Iterables&&... iters)
    -> typename std::enable_if<all_types_equal<Iterable::value_type...>::value, ChainObject<Iterables...> >::type
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I still have a lot to learn about C++. I'll revert back to using a plain old `enable_if` then :)

Comment: I tried, an the correct return type is `typename std::enable_if<all_types_equal<typename std::decay<Iterables>::type::value_type...>::value, ChainObject<Iterables...>>::type`.